# Socket communication in Android is not working

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator

I have a client application which is currently able to communicate to the server from android emulator.
It does **not work if I run it from my android phone**. What could be the possible issue..??

**Note**: Its a socket communication and I am using AsyncTask for the same and ensuring that I am not running in the main thread.
IP address and the port numbers are still the same.

Comment: Have you looked at the traffic via [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)? Can you ping your Android phone from your PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use socket communication by using your mobile , you should check whether your server ip is public ip that you can access in anywhere or not. unless ip address network is different between server and client (your mobile), It would run very well~